# JBoss Log Rotation with Date in current file

Tags: java, logging, jboss, elk

We are using the ˋPeriodicRotatingFileHandlerˋ in our JBoss applications.

What we would like to achieve is to log the current server log already in a file named `server.%{yyyy-MM-dd}.log`

So my log folder of today (2022-12-01) would look like the following:

```
server.2022-12-01.log <— the active / current log file
server.2022-11-30.log <— yesterdays log file 
server.2022-11-29.log <— …
```

Instead it looks currently like this:

```
server.log <— the active / current log file
server.2022-11-30.log <— yesterdays log file 
server.2022-11-29.log <— …
```

How can we achieve this within our `logging.properties` file which looks roughly like this:

```
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.FILE.constructorProperties=fileName,append
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.enabled=true
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.fileName=<dir left out>/server.log
```

Thanks for your help ☺️

Comment: You're only option would be to write a custom handler. I don't really know anything about Filebeat, but I would assume you could use some kind of pattern.

Comment: Well Filebeat is not really important. 
Important is only the desired output of the log files.

Can you maybe push me into the right direction regarding a custom handler?

Comment: A custom handler just needs to be an implementation of `java.util.logging.Handler`. You can see the `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler` [here](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/2.1.19.Final/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java). If this is WildFly or JBoss EAP BTW you'll need to edit more than just the `logging.properties`.